# Add post meta data date to event

Tags: post-meta, metabox

I created a post metabox that uses the datepicker to pick a date value. I got as far as adding the metabox  and getting the datepicker to work but other than that im struggling to get the data saved to the post. This is my code in my functions.php:

```
//Add date picker css
function admin_styles() {
    if ( 'events' === get_current_screen()->id ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-smoothness', // wrapped for brevity
            '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css', [], null );
    }
}
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'admin_styles');
//Activate function
function admin_scripts() {
    if ( 'events' === get_current_screen()->id ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'admin', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/admin.js', [ 'jquery-ui-datepicker' ] );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_scripts' );

//Add date meta-boxes 
function post_date_field($post) {
   echo '<input type="text" id="jquery-datepicker" name="entry_post_date" value="' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'entry_post_date', true ) . '">';
}
function post_date_meta_box() {
  add_meta_box('entry_post_date', 'Date', 'post_date_field', 'events', 'side', 'high');
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'post_date_meta_box');

//Save Data
function save_date_meta_box($post_id){
    global $post;
    if( $post->post_type == "events"){
        if (isset($_POST)){
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'entry_post_date', strip_tags( $_POST['entry_post_date'] ) );
        }
    }
}
```

After publishing or updating the post I dont think the date value is saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok silly me...
I missed this crucial line: `add_action( 'save_post', 'save_date_meta_box' );` It now seems to save the date values